# Set Placeholder attribute in Silex

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, silex

I'm building a form in Silex and I want to use the html5 placeholder attribute rather then just setting the prefill data of the input fields.

I'm trying to set it with following code:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
    ->add('email','email', array(
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Email'),
        'label' => 'Email'))
    ->add('password','password', array(
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Password'),
        'label' => 'Password'))
    ->getForm();
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
After putting following code in my twig template:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Following HTML is rendered:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<div id="form">
    <div>
        <label for="form_email" class="required"></label>
        <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="form_password" class="required"></label>
        <input type="password" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="03398bf6d8670d8de7a3800d9b49c91d21affbc3">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

How can i achieve the usage of placeholders within Silex?

---

**EDIT:** to call my template i use the following code:

```
return $app['twig']->render('index.twig',array(
    'form'=> $form->createView()
));
```

Comment: So it does output the attribute, but the value is empty?

Comment: indeed, it seems to recognize the attribute, but doesn't input the value. If double checked the documentation but can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me. Try running the code below. Put it in a new directory, run `composer install`, then run `php -S localhost:8000 app.php` to use the PHP development server (if you have PHP 5.4 or higher). This should replicate my setup as closely as possible. If this works, we can start figuring out why it didn't work for you.

#### composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "symfony/form": "~2.3",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
    "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
    "symfony/translation": "~2.3"
  }
}
```

#### app.php

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
  'twig.templates' => array(
    'form' => '<form action="#" method="post"> {{ form_widget(form) }} <input type="submit" name="submit" /> </form>'
  )
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
  'translator.messages' => array(),
));

$app->get('/', function() use($app) { 
  $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
    ->add('email','email', array(
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Email'),
        'label' => 'Email'))
    ->add('password','password', array(
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Password'),
        'label' => 'Password'))
    ->getForm();

  return $app['twig']->render('form', array('form'=> $form->createView()));
}); 

$app->run();
```

#### Result

```
<form action="#" method="post"> 
  <div id="form">
    <div>
      <label for="form_email" class="required">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="form_password" class="required">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="ba96e88afe7156803c70e41149a35d28edf80977" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: yes I am calling createView() in my rendering (adapted question)

Comment: Updated answer, did it in Silex. Try running what I have and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build the form manually:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_label(form.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Email'} }) }}

    {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
    {{ form_label(form.password) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```